# Handling Express Validator in a middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

The classic way shown in tutorials would be:

```
Router.post('/add-post', addPostValidation(), addPost)
```

But what if I want to do the validation in a middleware like this:

**The router:**

```
Router.post('/add-post', addPost)
```

**The middleware:**

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
   if(req.method == 'POST') {
      console.log('hello')
      body('name').notEmpty()
      let result = validationResult(req)
      console.log(result)
   }
   next()
}
```

The "hello" shows up but the **result** won't show me any error if I do this way

Comment: What does `validationResult`  function ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access a validation chain's `run` function to do what you want to do.

```
const addPost = (req, res, next) => {
  const validations = [
    body('name').notEmpty(),
    body('content').notEmpty(),
  ];
  await Promise.all(validations.map(chain => chain.run(req)));
  const result = validationResult(req);
  // ...
};
```

[Docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/6.14.0/running-imperatively)